# Get element which caused url change

Tags: jquery

i have this js code using jquery

```
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

on the bind event i want to get the src element like anchor tag etc

```
$(window).bind("hashchange", function (e) {
// .... element which caused this window event
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to retreive? the `href` value from an `<a>` tag?

Comment: <a> tag which caused window to trigger this event ....

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the [source](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.js), specifically for the "trigger" function (as that is what is used to send events), I have found that there is no data attached to these hashchange events. If you would like to find the info anyway, you can capture clicks on all links and then use that to figure this out.

```
$('a').click(function() {
        window.lastclickedanchor = this;
});
```

This function will allow you to track which links are clicked. Just access the window.lastclickedanchor property and you will be able to tell who clicked what.

-Sunjay03